# Draggable not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

Hi all  i have a function where i have to drag and drop elements here  is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var i = 0;
    $("button[id='columnadd']").click(function () {
        alert(1);
            var domElement = $('<aside id="shoppingCart' + i + '" class="shoppingCart"><h2 class="ui-widget-header">Add Menu Items Here</h2><aside class="ui-widget-content" id="droppable"><ol><li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li></ol></aside></aside>');
            i++;
            $(this).after(domElement);
    });

        $(".small_box li" ).draggable({
            appendTo: "body",
            helper: "clone"
        });
});

$('#shoppingCart ol').droppable({
    accept: '.small_box li',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        alert(1);
        $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
        $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);
    }
});
```

here is my html:

```
    <aside class="small_box">
    <h4>BRANDS</h4>
    <ul>
        <li id ="brand1"><a class="" href="#">Brand1</a></li>
        <li id ="brand2"><a href="#">Brand2</a></li>
        <li id ="brand3"><a href="#">Brand3</a></li>
        <li id ="brand4"><a href="#">Brand4</a></li>
     </ul>
    </aside>
```

i should be able to drop in at this place `<li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li>`

```
var domElement = $('<aside id="shoppingCart' + i + '" class="shoppingCart"><h2 class="ui-widget-header">Add Menu Items Here</h2><aside class="ui-widget-content" id="droppable"><ol><li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li></ol></aside></aside>');
```

any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please fix your code indentations.

There are some mistakes on your code:

1. `var i = 0;`
   I think it should be a global variable. So put it outside your `$(document).ready(function() {})` block;
2. You create a DOM Element (which is the drop area) upon click and this element is not in your page until you click the trigger. By doing `$('#shoppingCart ol').droppable({...})` in `$(document).ready(function() {})` block you try to add `droppable` to an element that even not in your page, so this won't do a thing.

What you should do is make the element `droppable` **after** you create that element and put it on your page. here's an example:

```
$("button[id='columnadd']").click(function () {
  // create the element
  var domElement = $('<aside id="shoppingCart' + i++ + '" class="shoppingCart"><h2 class="ui-widget-header">Add Menu Items Here</h2><aside class="ui-widget-content" id="droppable"><ol><li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li></ol></aside></aside>');

  // put it after $(this)
  $(this).after(domElement);
  // at this point you have domElement in your page

  // make it droppable
  domElement.find("ol").droppable({
    // put options here
    greedy: true,
    drop: function (event, ui) {
      makeItDroppableToo(event, ui, this);
    }
  });
});
```

and this is the function to make your dropped element has its own placeholder

```
function makeItDroppableToo(e, ui, obj) {
  $(obj).find(".placeholder").remove();

  var placeholder = $("<ol><li class='placeholder'>You can also drop it here</li></ol>");
  $("<li></li>").append(ui.draggable.text()).append(placeholder).appendTo($(obj));

  // this is the same as the previous one
  placeholder.droppable({
    // put options here
    greedy: true,
    drop: function (event, ui) {
      makeItDroppableToo(event, ui, this);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks it's working now....if i want to add sub item to already dropped elemtn how can i do this...can u please help me out

Comment: I've updated my answer. It has basically the same principles. create it > put it on the page > add some behaviors (events)

Comment: Thank you for your response..but when i add sub the sub item is also added and the same on is dropped as main element too..

Comment: use `greedy: true` on droppable options. It will make the first droppable triggered not sharing its event to its parent. I've tested it and I think this will answer your question :)

Comment: ...how to get an Dropped element as draggable

Comment: clone the `ui.draggable` then make it droppable

Comment: at the `drop` function, use this: `$(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo(something here).droppable({});` please read the API documentation. I'm not your programmer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle, I was working with JQueryUI

http://jsfiddle.net/ashpriom/yHLGP/

```
  $(function() {
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this )
      .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
      .find( "p" )
        .html( "Dropped!" );
  }
});
```

});